# What does an exclamation mark in array index do?

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, indexer, not-operator

While perusing through my organization's source repository I came across this little gem:

```
RawParameterStorage[!ParameterWorkingIdx][ParameterDataOffset] = ...
```

Is this valid code? (It compiles)  What does the exclamation mark here do?

An invert `~` operator might make sense, since it's commonly confused with the not `!` operator in boolean expressions.  However, it doesn't seem to make logical sense to impose the not `!` operator on an array index. Any Thoughts?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

`!ParameterWorkingIdx` Means `ParameterWorkingIdx` is `0`, If it is, `!ParameterWorkingIdx` evaluates as `true` which might be implicitly converted to the indexer type (For example, `1` for integer indexer as in an array), otherwise, it evaluates as `false`.

- If `ParameterWorkingIdx == 0` then `[!ParameterWorkingIdx] == [1]`.
- If `ParameterWorkingIdx != 0` then `[!ParameterWorkingIdx] == [0]`.

It also depends on other stuff like:

- The type of `ParameterWorkingIdx`.
- overloading of `! operator` by the type of `ParameterWorkingIdx`.
- indexer overloading by the type of `RawParameterStorage`.
- etc...

Comment: `"You " + ["are", "are not"][!loggedIn()] + " logged in."` ← an example of the same idea in JavaScript. Agreed icky, but not C's fault!

Comment: I think you need to remove the "different than" from the first sentence. In its current form it's the opposite of what you want to say.

Comment: @j6m8 actually that doesn't work as in JS, properties are cast to strings and booleans end up as `"true"`/`"false"` then. So either use `"You "+["are not", "are"][+loggedIn()]+" logged in"` or `"You "+{false:"are not", true:"are"}[loggedIn()]+" logged in"`

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy C is like a kitten, C++ is more like a zoo. It's nice, in its own overwhelming way ;)

Answer (score 19):

Taking a bit of a guess here, but that looks like a double-buffer pattern. `ParameterWorkingIdx` would flip-flop between `0` and `1` (probably with `ParameterWorkingIdx = !ParameterWorkingIdx;`).

Then, at any time, `RawParameterStorage[ParameterWorkingIdx]` would be the current buffer, and `RawParameterStorage[!ParameterWorkingIdx]` would be the previous buffer.

Answer (score 8):

> it doesn't seem to make logical sense to impose the not `!` operator on an array index

It might: all it does here is convert zero to one, and any other number to zero.

We can infer from this code that `RawParameterStorage` probably has two elements at the top level.

P. S. Here, I assume that `RawParameterStorage` is an array (as you say it is). Furthermore, I assume that `ParameterWorkingIdx` is an integer (as its name implies). If, for example, either is a class with overloaded operators than the semantics could be completely different.

Comment: UV'd but this does assume that `ParameterWorkingIdx` is not an instance of a class with an overloaded ! operator. The OP would be wise to check that.

Comment: @Bathsheba: Fair point. I'll add a few words for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this valid code?

Yes it is. Suppose `ParameterWorkingIdx` to be an `int`, for `!ParameterWorkingIdx`, when used with `operators !`, it'll be [contextually convertible to bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Contextual_conversions),

> The value zero (for integral, floating-point, and unscoped enumeration) and the null pointer and the null pointer-to-member values become `false`. All other values become `true`.

Then [integral promoted](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) to be used as the array index.

> the type bool can be converted to int with the value `false` becoming ​0​ and `true` becoming 1.

So `!ParameterWorkingIdx` is equivalent with `ParameterWorkingIdx == 0 ? 1 : 0`, which is much more clear IMO.

Comment: By writing it like this you don't generate a branch instruction in your code, although the immediate purpose might not be obvious...

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu We're writing code for human to be read, not just for computer. :)

Comment: If performance of this chunk is important enough that avoiding the branch instruction is helpful, just add the ternary-conditional version as a comment. Or a plain-English version of the same.

Comment: What I meant to say is that when the immediate purpose is not obvious one should make it obvious with comments, what @David Heyman said

Comment: @XapaJIaMnu In such cases, clear and unambiguous documentation explaining why the special kind of language sorcery had to be invoked should've been placed in the source code.

Comment: For the readable version (`ParameterWorkingIdx == 0 ? 1 : 0`) clang uses the `cmove` instruction and does not branch (x86_64). gcc does.